# Related to super and sub class

Tags: default-constructor

I'm a beginner in java

```
class A{
    {
        Sopln("IB in A");
    }
    static {
        Sopln(" SB in A");
    }
    A() {
        Sopln(" delt in A);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    {
        Sopln(" IB in A");
    }
    static {
        Sopln(" sb in B");
    }
    B() {
        Sopln(" deflt in B");
    }
}

class Hello {
    Psvm(String arg[]){
        B b1= new B();
    }
}
```

Actual output:-

`Sb in A
Sb in B
Ib in A 
Deflt in A
Ib in B
Deflt in B`

But according to me.....if class A loaded first then all members of class A process first and then members of B

If class B loaded first then all members of class B are processed first then all members of B

Please explain me the reason behind this

Comment: Hi Priyanka, wc to community. Please use paragraphs and editing provided by the site, so that we can help you better. Also please avoid using abbreviations or atleast give their long forms. :)

Comment: Thank u sir!!!   Sir please tell me how to use editing provided by the site......actually i'm new for this so i don't know

Comment: stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Ohk....thank u very much